# Why is my WCF ServiceAuthorizationManager being called twice on each request?

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, iis

I have implemented a ServiceAuthorizationManager in my WCF service running under IIS 7.5 on Server 2k8. The CheckAccessCore function is being called twice for each incoming request. The first time CheckAccessCore is called the Authorization header is there and the user is authenticated. The second time CheckAccessCore is called the Authorization header is empty and authentication obviously fails. Why is the second part happening?

Interace:

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="", Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Function ProcessMessage(ByVal value As Stream) As Stream
```

web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyDataService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RestSSL"> 
      <security mode="Transport">

      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/OtherSvcLib/Service1/"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyDataService"
    contract="DataService.IMyDataService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyDataService" />
</client>
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceLib.MyHubSvcLib" behaviorConfiguration="gogogo">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="RestSSL"
              behaviorConfiguration="RestSvcBehavior" 
              contract="MyServiceLib.IMyService"> 
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://mydomain.com/MyServiceLib/MyHub.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="gogogo">
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyServiceLib.clsCustomAuthManager, MyServiceLib">

      </serviceAuthorization>

      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestSvcBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: How did you find out that it is being called twice for the same request?

Comment: @usr I started writing the header contents to a text file whenever the method is called.

Comment: Are you sure your service is only being called once?

Comment: Its being called with HttpWebRequest from a little winform test client I tossed together. Pretty sure the method is only firing once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Looks like maybe IIS didn't like the ambiguous(?) uriTemplate in my interface and was forwarding or redirecting the request or maybe it was something else, I'm not going to spend any more time investigating it. I simply added "/" to the uriTemplate and the URL in the client.

Does not work: (request to mydomain.com/service.svc)

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="", Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Function ProcessMessage(ByVal value As Stream) As Stream
```

DOES work: (request to mydomain.com/service.svc/ ) Note the "/" in UriTemplate:="/"

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="/", Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Function ProcessMessage(ByVal value As Stream) As Stream
```